# Is it "at the porch" or "on the porch"?

Tags: prepositions

a) She was reading a book ON the porch.

b) She was reading a book AT the porch.

Which is correct?

Comment: It depends, was she on the porch or at the porch? The one that's correct is the one that describes her actual relationship to the porch.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Right on. [This lad](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cOuml.jpg), for example, is reading **at** the porch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say either one is "incorrect," but I would say that ***on** the porch* is far more common, and the one you should probably use. The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20the%20porch,on%20the%20porch&year_start=1925&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,at%20the%20porch;,c0;.t1;,on%20the%20porch;,c0) would agree with me.

Incidentally, while the Ngram does show some hits for *at the porch*, many of those are in an entirely different context, such as:

> He glanced at the porch, where he saw...
>   She stood at the porch railing, looking out onto the street.

Comment: To be, perhaps, a bit pedantic: If people were, say, painting a house, and one man is standing outside the porch painting it, and someone asked where he was, we might say he is "at the porch". That is, we could say "at the porch" to refer to someone who is beside or near the porch but not actually on it.

Comment: @Jay - Not pedantic at all, I don't think. It's a valid comment, akin to what David mentioned in his comment to the O.P. One can indeed read **at** the porch, particularly when one is at the porch, but not on it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure we had a long discussion of the proper use of "place" prepositions, but I can't find it now.

In general, we say "on" for something that a person or object can be standing or resting on top of. We say "in" for something that physically surrounds you. We say "at" for things that you would be beside or in front of or in the general vicinity of.

So, "She was on the front lawn." "She was in the living room." "She was at 47 Grover Street."

"In" is used both in the case of something that physically encloses someone or some thing, like a box or a room with walls that reach to the ceiling, and also for very large areas, like a city. If someone is standing on a sidewalk in New York City, we will say that he is "on the sidewalk", but he is "in New York".

As a porch does not normally have walls that reach the ceiling, we say "on the porch" rather than "in the porch".

Comment: This may be worth emphasizing: Even when a porch _does_ have walls that reach the ceiling (such as a screened porch), I would _still_ say, "Reading **on** the porch..." (but, "Reading **in** the kitchen...").

Comment: True. I think idiomatic usage is based on the standard case rather than the details of the specific case.

Comment: In this hypothetical, the screens don't seem like walls to me.  I think if you had "wall" walls all around the porch, it would cease to be a porch in my mind!

Comment: snailboat: Except in odd cases, maybe. Like, when I was a kid, my grandparents had a house with a porch, but then they built walls to turn it into another room. But we all still called it "the porch", and when someone was in that room we said they were "on the porch". And now I'm having all these nostalgic thoughts about eating Neapolitan ice cream and playing board games on my grandparents' porch. :-)